# Why does NSCalendar have two init methods with similar parameter types that accepts one of the calendar identifier constants?

Tags: ios, swift, initialization, nscalendar

Why does NSCalendar have two init methods with similar parameter types that both accept one of the calendar identifier constants?  What is the point of having two init methods that do the exact same thing?  Does anyone know the reasoning behind why Apple would add this information to the documentation this way or why the class is even created this way?

Here is the first init method:

```
init?(calendarIdentifier ident: String)
```

Here is the second init method:

```
init?(identifier calendarIdentifierConstant: String)
```

[Link to Apple's NSCalendar Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSCalendar/calendarWithIdentifier:)

Comment: @LeoDabus Is there a reason why a developer would want to use the string version instead of the enum version which never fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Objective-C, there are two renditions, `calendarWithIdentifier` convenience method that returns `autorelease` object and `initWithCalendarIdentifier` that returns a `+1` object. The distinction of the `autorelease` object and the `+1` object has little practical implication nowadays (and really only comes into play if you were allocating and releasing many of them inside a loop, which you're unlikely to be doing with this class).

In Swift, they both resolve to `init?`, the first with a parameter called `identifier` and the other whose parameter is `calendarIdentifier`.

Note, in Swift 3, this confusion is eliminated, both converted to `init?(identifier:)`.

Answer (score 3):

That seems to be a bug in the Swift 2 import of the Objective-C interface.
In Objective-C there are – at it is usual with Foundation classes – 
both a instance method

```
- (id)initWithCalendarIdentifier:(NSString *)string
// Initializes a newly-allocated NSCalendar object for the calendar specified by a given identifier.
```

and a class (factory method):

```
+ (NSCalendar *)calendarWithIdentifier:(NSString *)calendarIdentifierConstant
// Creates and returns a new NSCalendar object specified by a given identifier.
```

and the following two statements are (almost) equivalent:

```
NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"..."];
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar calendarWithIdentifier:@"..."];
```

In Swift there are only initializers, and both should be mapped
to the same Swift initializer (as it is the case with other Foundation
classes). Apparently that does not work correctly, but the result
is identical:

```
let cal1 = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierChinese)
let cal2 = NSCalendar(identifier: NSCalendarIdentifierChinese)
print(cal1 == cal2) // true
```

In *Swift 3* there is only one initializer, taking an `NSCalendar.Identifier`
parameter:

```
let cal = NSCalendar(identifier: .chinese)
```

(or the new value type

```
let cal = Calendar(identifier: .chinese)
```

which takes an enumeration parameter).